# How to do remove flat sides?

Tags: geometry-nodes

How get rid of the flat sides. Is this can be achieved?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by falloff density? A smooth transition from no mesh to mesh? But that's not possible, there is no such thing as a "half-mesh", a mesh cannot have different or increasing densities like a volume. Sure, in real life wood and steel for example have different densities. But the surface is the surface, it's not like any of them start of with a transparent surface that's slowly getting more and more opaque.

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense. Falloff density? What is that? You should edit the question and clarify if you expect meaningful help. Could you maybe provide an image of some sort of example of what it should look like?

Comment: Hello, ShockWave.. I'm understanding this to mean fade the hard clamp which gives away the flat walls of the cube. Is that right? Please edit the post to make that clear, if it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am assuming, that you just wanna get rid of the flat sides, so with this node setup:

[image]

you will get this:

[image]

basically the node setup decreases/limits the density to a sphere, hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what was needed! Thanks a lot!

Comment: you are welcome